# Find images with special characters on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, filenames

I have around 10k images and I need to find just the ones which have special characters and accents (like á, é, í, ...). The idea would be to keep those images with special characters and delete all the other ones.

How could this be done on Mac terminal?

Thank you in advance,
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

If only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, spaces and hyphens are allowed as an example:

```
> find /path/to/your/images | egrep [^A-Za-z0-9./\ -]
```